# ¿Cómo puedo pasar datos de una fila de un JTable a campos jTextField?

Tags: java, jframe, jtable, jtextfield

Quisiera seleccionar una fila de un `JTable`, pulsar un button"`button_comprar`" y que se carguen en unos `jTextField` en un JDialog.

**Compra.java** (donde tengo el JTable y el botón):

```
     private void button_comprarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        int filaseleccionada;
        try{
            //Guardamos en un entero la fila seleccionada.
            filaseleccionada = table_comprados.getSelectedRow();
            if (filaseleccionada == -1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No ha seleccionado ninguna fila.");
            } else {
                Comprar_vehiculo cv = new Comprar_vehiculo(null, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
                cv.setVisible(true);
                pasarDatosFila();
            }
        }catch (HeadlessException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+ex+"\nInténtelo nuevamente", " .::Error En la Operacion::." ,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }        
    }                                              

    public void pasarDatosFila(){
        int filaseleccionada = table_comprados.getSelectedRow();
        String bastidor = (String)table_comprados.getValueAt(filaseleccionada, 0);
        String color = (String)table_comprados.getValueAt(filaseleccionada, 1);
        String matricula = (String)table_comprados.getValueAt(filaseleccionada, 2);
        String marca = (String)table_comprados.getValueAt(filaseleccionada, 3);

        //Volcamos los datos de la tabla en los jTextFields.
        Object[] vc = new Object[4];
        vc[0] = bastidor;
        vc[1] = color;
        vc[2] = matricula;
        vc[3] = marca;
    }
```

**Comprar_vehiculo.java** (donde tengo el JDialog con jTextFields):

```
//Volcamos los datos de la tabla en los jTextFields.
textfield_marca.setText(String.valueOf(v[0]));
textfield_marca.setEditable(false);
¿?¿?¿?
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que estas teniendo? Podrías agregar a tu pregunta

Comment: No sé cómo pasar los datos del JTable a unos campos jTextField de un archivo .java a otro.

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta lo que acabas de agregar al comentario

Comment: Ya lo hice. No sé que como relacionarlo.

Comment: ¿Alguna posible solución a mi problema?

Comment: De poder se puede. Pero en el JTable puede tener miles de filas. O vos quisieras tener de una fila específica y mostrar en un JTextField.

Comment: Al seleccionar una fila con click sobre la fila y pulsar el botón que envie los datos a los jTextField.

Comment: No sé por qué no has borrado esta pregunta si tienes una en la que preguntas lo mismo y has marcado una respuesta válida.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, lo que creo que debes hacer es seleccionar la fila con el click. Esto se hace con el método `getSelectedRow()`.

Luego que ya tengas la fila seleccionada, vamos a obtener sus datos, usa el método más sencillo de todos `toString()`.

Ya que tengas la fila seleccionada y los datos, lo puedes mostrar donde quieras con el método `setText`, y listo.

Comment: Sí eso lo entiendo, pero no creo que sea tan sencillo como eso, debido a que necesito que se carguen al pulsar el botón (evento actionPerformed()) y necesito sacar los datos de la tabla con getValueAt. ¿Pero cómo lo traslado de una clase a otra? Es decir, en el Compra.java pulso la fila de la tabla y pulso el botón "Comprar" y al pulsar el botón COMPRAR se me carga otro .java llamado "Vehiculo_compra" y se cargan los datos en éste en campos jTextField.